# Creating MBTiles file with varied levels of detail using existing OpenMapTiles docker tasks?

Tags: docker, openmaptiles

I'm working hard to get up to speed with OpenMapTiles. The `quickstart.sh` script usually runs to completion so I've preferred it as a source of truth over the sometimes inconsistent documentation. Time to evolve.

What is the most efficient way to build an MBTiles file that contains, say, *planet-level* data for zooms 0-6 and *bounded* data for zooms 7-13, ideally for multiple bounded areas (e.g., a handful of metro areas). Seems a common use case during development. Can it be done with the existing Docker tools?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to download a OSM file from http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html and place it in /data folder, as stated in the quickstart.md (https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles/blob/master/QUICKSTART.md) ?

Placing the osm.pbf file in your /data folder and adjusting the .env and openmaptiles.yaml file to your preferred zoom should help you with a next step.

I'm not sure what you mean with the bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What I meant by "with the bounds" is that I'd like to create a single MBTiles file that has full planet coverage for zooms 0-6 and zoom 7-13 coverage for one or more areas of interest, say a metropolitan area or an individual country.   I ended up generating one MBTiles file for the world from zooms 0-6, one MBTiles file for each area of interest from 0-13, then hosting a TileServer GL instance for each. Not ideal but it works as the team iterates on feature inclusion and styles. I'll generate the full planet 0-13 once things settle down.